# How to display range of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in dygraphs

Tags: date-range, dygraphs

i have a csv where I collect data. CSV looks like this:

```
date_time,temp
2014-10-14 03:37:56,21.50
2014-10-14 03:53:04,21.56
2014-10-14 04:08:12,21.50
2014-10-14 04:23:19,21.50
2014-10-14 04:38:27,21.44
2014-10-14 04:53:35,21.50
2014-10-14 05:08:43,21.50
2014-10-14 05:23:51,21.44
2014-10-14 05:38:58,21.38
2014-10-14 05:54:06,21.44
2014-10-14 06:09:14,21.44
2014-10-14 06:24:22,21.38
2014-10-14 06:39:29,21.38
2014-10-14 06:54:37,21.38
```

Then I have this code in a html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="labeldiv" style="width:100%; height:20px;"></div>
<div id="graphdiv" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  g = new Dygraph( 
    document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
    "test.csv",
    {
    strokeWidth: 2.5,
    labelsSeparateLines: false,
    labelsDiv: "labeldiv",
    legend: "always",
    showRangeSelector: true,
    } 
  );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It works correctly, but I would like to have a possibility to select only certain date and time period and not to display the whole period from CSV.
I tried specifying parameter like `dateWindow: ["2014-10-14 04:53:35","2014-10-14 06:09:14"]` but it seems to be not working.

Could anybody help me with this? Is it possible to do it in a way I am trying? Do I have to convert the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to something else before using in dateWindow?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `dateWindow`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#dateWindow) states:

> Initially zoom in on a section of the graph. Is of the form [earliest,
>   latest], where earliest/latest are milliseconds since epoch. If the
>   data for the x-axis is numeric, the values in dateWindow must also be
>   numbers.
>
> *Type: Array of two numbers*
>   *Default: Full range of the input is shown*

So you should set:

```js
dateWindow: [Date.parse("2014-10-14 04:53:35"),
             Date.parse("2014-10-14 06:09:14")]
```

Comment: `dateWindow: [Date.parse("2014-10-14 04:53:35"),             Date.parse("2014-10-14 06:09:14")]` **did not work.** But then I found this to be working:`dateWindow: [Date.parse("2014/10/14 04:53:35"),Date.parse("2014/10/14 06:09:14")]` **So there has to be slashes used instead of dashes.** Thanks anyway for good hint!

Comment: Can you clarify what "did not work" means? The slashes vs. dashes determine whether the data is parsed using local time or UTC. See http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html.

Comment: I have a csv with this format `2014-10-14 03:37:56,21.50` and when used `dateWindow: [Date.parse("2014-10-14 04:53:35"),Date.parse("2014-10-14 06:09:14")]`, then there was no graph line drawn and the range selector was completely on the left - out of range. Once I switch to `dateWindow: [Date.parse("2014/10/14 04:53:35"),Date.parse("2014/10/14 06:09:14")]`, the graph is drawn correctly and range correctly selected. I use Firefox 32.0.

Comment: In Firefox, Date.parse("2014-10-14 04:53:35")=NaN whereas Date.parse("2014/10/14 04:53:35")=1413276815000. They return the same thing in Chrome. dygraphs has helpfully [converted](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/dygraph-utils.js#L614) your dashes to slashes when it parsed your data, so you never noticed!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a workaround. I call dygraph from a php page that selects the data to be displayed (last 24 hours, last week, last month or everything).
One advantage is that for big data files, you do not need to send everything and it can be appreciably faster, not because dygraph is slow (it is not) but because you have less data to send over the wire.
Once that selection of data is loaded, you can easily select a smaller section, but if you want a bigger selection, you have to go back to the calling page.

Comment: Yes, I have changed my "project" to store the temperatures into  mysql database table and created php script which fetches only desired time period from database.

Answer (score 0):

Using a mysql database to store time-lapse data seems overkill to me, but that is one way to do it.
I normally reserve databases for cases where individual records need to be accessed and modified, possibly by multiple simultaneous users, or the data needs to be sorted according to multiple criteria. For time-lapse data, a comma-delimited flat file that you append to is much more efficient.
In my case, I convert the date/time stamp into a Unix time variable format before saving to the file. That makes later selection of a time frame very easy. Then I can convert the time variable into a human readable time/date string format in PHP before sending it to the browser, or in the JavaScript before sending to dygraph.